# How can I use automodule or autoclass for Sphinx in a markdown file?

Tags: python, python-sphinx, read-the-docs, autodoc

I understand the Sphinx supports markdown or .md files optionally, which works great for me for my supplimental documentation. What I am trying to do is use the `autoclass` or `automodule` tags in a markdown file.

Normally, in a `.rst` file, if I do

```
.. autoclass:: my.module.SomeClass
    :members:
```

it will automatically pull all the docstrings and create the documentation. Is it possible to use this in `.md` files? At the moment, when I attempt to do so, the generated docs only contains `.. autoclass:...` which is expected.

My `conf.py` is

```py
extensions = ["sphinx.ext.autodoc", "sphinx.ext.napoleon", "recommonmark"]
source_suffix = {
    '.rst': 'restructuredtext',
    '.txt': 'markdown',
    '.md': 'markdown',
}
```

Because of read the docs compatibility, I did consider mkdocs, but it does not offer autodoc like capabilities. I am very open to any other library (does not have to be RTD compatible) in order to accomplish this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Use [MyST](https://myst-parser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

```
pip install myst-parser
```

Add this extension to your sphinx config:

```
extensions = [..., "myst_parser"]
```

Use `{eval-rst}` with `autoclass` role, within a ```` ``` ```` block

````
```{eval-rst}  
.. autoclass:: my.module.SomeClass
:members:
```
````

### Old, deprecated way

This might require using [AutoStructify](https://recommonmark.readthedocs.io/en/latest/auto_structify.html#autostructify-component) of Recommonmark, namely the [RST embedding](https://recommonmark.readthedocs.io/en/latest/auto_structify.html#embed-restructuredtext) feature.

With it, you'd add the following to your markdown:

````
 ```eval_rst
 .. autoclass:: my.module.SomeClass
 :members:
 ```
````

Answer (score 2):

Adding the ".md" to the `source_suffix` list worked for me:

In your conf.py:

```
# The suffix(es) of source filenames.
# You can specify multiple suffix as a list of string:
source_suffix = ['.rst', '.md']
```

I am using sphinx 2.1.2

Answer (score 1):

If you're using [MyST](https://github.com/executablebooks/MyST-Parser):

```
extensions = [
    'myst_parser',
    ...
]
```

All you need to do is:

````
```{eval_rst}
 .. autoclass:: my.module.SomeClass
 :members:
```
````